# Data stream received from a bar code scanner

Tags: barcode-scanner

Were moving to using 2d bar codes and 2d bar code scanners.  Currently a picker will scan 3 linear bar codes, one for the product, one for the lot number and one for the quantity.  The cursor starts in the Product field, after the scan the cursor moves to the lot number field the repeats the process for the quantity.  Each scan contains data only for the field intended.  Well along comes the 2d bar codes that concatenate all three values into 1 returned string with application identifiers (01,11,10) separating each 'field'.  An example of this is (01)12345678901234(11)220728(10)12345.  The parentheses are not included in the actual scan, I just showed them for demonstration purposes.  My question is how do I know when to parse out each field?  For example, in a CSV file, I just look for data in between the commas.  I've also read something about FNC1.  Can anyone help?  Thanks...

2d bar code

[image: 1]

Scanner results

[image: 2]

Comment: The question is not very clear. Could you show some actual data, for the actual problem to be solved? I.e. an excerpt from the CSV file or whatever you're working with. Also show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the information on these pages.

This page contains ideas and flowcharts.
[GS1 DataMatrix Guideline](https://www.gs1.org/standards/gs1-datamatrix-guideline/25)

You can find a list of application identifiers on this page.
[GS1 Application Identifiers](https://www.gs1.org/standards/barcodes/application-identifiers)

Please use the above in combination to help you implement it.